# Unicode for X-double bar

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

I am looking for the HTML code for the X-double bar.

I know the code for a single bar:

x-bar = `x&amp;#772;` or `x&amp;#x0304;` (hex)

But what is it for the X-double bar?

Comment: www.unicode.org. http://www.fileformat.info/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U+0304 is the combining macron.  There is a "combining double overline" at U+033F which might work for you, and a "combining double macron" at U+035E.  Neither of these looks very clearly like a double bar in my browser.  But if they work for you, the code would be something like `&#x033F;x` which renders as ̿x or `&#x035E;x` which renders as ͞x  (This is HTML markup, not Unicode.)  Note also that the combining character should go before the character it combines with, not after.

See also http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm

Comment: Actually `&#x033F;` is HTML syntax for a character reference referring to a Unicode character. So it's **both**: HTML *and* Unicode.

Comment: @Joachim: yes; I am mainly noting the terminological discrepancy in his question; after all, I was able to understand what he was asking.  Also note that I expanded the answer a little bit; U+035E looks better at least in my browser.

Comment: @Joachim. Yes am using it for kindle which uses plain HTML

Comment: @triplee. and what if my x is capital i.e X

Comment: Then you combine with an uppercase X instead.  You can basically combine with anything -- say, a dollar sign; `&#x035E;$`

Comment: @triplee: You cannot put combining characters before the character they combine with: they follow it.  If you write `"a\x{301}b"`, then that acjute accent mark falls on the `a` not the `b`.

Answer (score 9):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

U+035E `COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON` is meant to go over two code points.  It is double only in the sense that it goes over both the code point it follows and the one it precedes, unlike normal marks that only count for the one they follow.  Compare U+0360 `COMBINING DOUBLE TILDE`, which does the same thing. `"a\x{35e}e"` is `a͞e`, while `"a\x{360}e"` is `a͠e`.

The code point you want is U+033F `COMBINING DOUBLE OVERLINE`.  `"x\x{33f}"` is `x̿`.

Here are all the combining macrons, using the [*uninames* tool](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniname):

```
% uninames COMBINING MACRON
  ̄  0304        COMBINING MACRON
        = long
        * distinguish from the following
        x (macron - 00AF)
        x (modifier letter macron - 02C9)
  ̱  0331        COMBINING MACRON BELOW
        x (low line - 005F)
        x (modifier letter low macron - 02CD)
  ͞  035E        COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON
  ͟  035F        COMBINING DOUBLE MACRON BELOW
  ᷄  1DC4       COMBINING MACRON-ACUTE
  ᷅  1DC5       COMBINING GRAVE-MACRON
  ᷆  1DC6       COMBINING MACRON-GRAVE
  ᷇  1DC7       COMBINING ACUTE-MACRON
  ᷋  1DCB       COMBINING BREVE-MACRON
        * Lithuanian dialectology
  ᷌  1DCC       COMBINING MACRON-BREVE
        * Lithuanian dialectology
  ︤  FE24       COMBINING MACRON LEFT HALF
  ︥  FE25       COMBINING MACRON RIGHT HALF
  ︦  FE26       COMBINING CONJOINING MACRON
        x (combining macron - 0304)
        x (combining double macron - 035E)
```

and here are the combining half marks:

```
% uninames COMBINING HALF

  ̜  031C        COMBINING LEFT HALF RING BELOW
        * IPA: open variety of vowel
        x (modifier letter down tack - 02D5)
  ̹  0339        COMBINING RIGHT HALF RING BELOW
  ͑  0351        COMBINING LEFT HALF RING ABOVE
  ͗  0357        COMBINING RIGHT HALF RING ABOVE
  ︠  FE20        COMBINING LIGATURE LEFT HALF
  ︡  FE21        COMBINING LIGATURE RIGHT HALF
        x (combining double inverted breve - 0361)
  ︢  FE22        COMBINING DOUBLE TILDE LEFT HALF
  ︣  FE23        COMBINING DOUBLE TILDE RIGHT HALF
        x (combining double tilde - 0360)
  ︤  FE24       COMBINING MACRON LEFT HALF
  ︥  FE25       COMBINING MACRON RIGHT HALF
```

And these are, well, what they say they are:

```
% uninames COMBINING DOUBLE LINE
  ̎  030E        COMBINING DOUBLE VERTICAL LINE ABOVE
        * Marshallese
        x (quotation mark - 0022)
  ̳  0333        COMBINING DOUBLE LOW LINE
        = double underline, double underscore
        * connects on left and right
        x (combining equals sign below - 0347)
        x (double low line - 2017)
  ̿  033F        COMBINING DOUBLE OVERLINE
  ͈  0348        COMBINING DOUBLE VERTICAL LINE BELOW
        * IPA: strong articulation

$ uninames '\bAE\b' macron
 Ǣ  01E2        LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE WITH MACRON
        : 00C6 0304
 ǣ  01E3        LATIN SMALL LETTER AE WITH MACRON
        * Old Norse, Old English
        : 00E6 0304
```

You can test them this out way:

```
$ export PERL_UNICODE=S

$ perl -E 'say "x\x{33f}"'
x̿

$ perl -E 'say "a\x{35e}e"'
a͞e
$ perl -E 'say "a\x{360}e"'
a͠e
$ perl -E 'say "a\x{fe24}e\x{fe25}"'
a︤e︥

$ perl -E 'say "\x{1e3}"'
ǣ
$ perl -E 'say "\x{e6}\x{304}"'
ǣ
$ perl -E 'say "\x{e6}\x{33f}"'
æ̿

$ perl -E 'say "X\x{304}"'
X̄
$ perl -E 'say "X\x{33f}"'
X̿
$ perl -E 'say "x\x{33f}\x{333}"'
x̳̿
```

Comment: Those Perl one-liners only work on Unix-like systems, not Windows. On Windows `"` and `'` are reversed - `"` delimits the one-liner text and it can not immediately be used inside. For instance, for the first one, `perl -E "say "x\x{33f}""` results in "`Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "33f" (Missing operator before f?) syntax error at -e line 1, near "33f" Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.`". Used as is it gives: `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`.

Answer (score 2):

For whichever character you want to put bars above, add `&#772;` after it.

So for example if you want x double bar (x̄̄) the HTML code is `x&#772;&#772;`.  If you want to make an x triple bar (x̄̄̄) then write `x&#772;&#772;&#772;`.

Here's a code sample in HTML:

```html
X single bar: x&#772;<br>
X double bar: x&#772;&#772;<br>
X triple bar: x&#772;&#772;&#772;<br>
```

This also works for any character.  For example, for y triple bar (ȳ̄̄), it will be `y&#772;&#772;&#772;`.

Comment: out of all solutions, this one worked without texts going haywire. Very simple method too.